# How can I view my Facebook ad as others see it?

Tags: facebook, ads

I am a new small business and did my first paid ad this morning. Is there a way to see like a screenshot of someone's Facebook page with my ad showing on it? I have no clue what it looks like when posted on Facebook other than the preview of what Facebook shows me.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Facebook for Business](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/150467178355530), you can see it under Manage Your Ads, which is different than the preview you only see while creating the ad.  If this isn't working for you, you're welcome to link it and I'll screenshot what I see. Note, however, you don't have to be logged into Facebook to see Facebook content. It's just better formatted when you are.

Comment: I was able to see it as newsfeed finally but it just appears like any other post I would do with photos. I guess what I really wanted to see was how it was shown to others. But since I don't know who saw it I cannot do that. Does it look like the ones in my newsfeed that say "sponsored" beside the name of the business?

Comment: I'm not seeing it on your FB page, but I'm not your sponsored audience, so I wouldn't.  Also, you don't exist on Google while your FB page says "Ask for Home Grown Nursery's Hours" and "Ask for Home Grown Nursery's Website.".  That's more important than a FB dark post.  In answer to your question, I can't even see the ads on Google Images because you don't come up in search.